# In what churches does this set of beliefs and behaviors best fit?

Tags: denomination-survey

The church in question believes or behaves in the following ways:

1. Jesus is the Messiah.
2. Jesus is the Son of God, but he is not God, nor is equal to God in anyway. He taught us about God and his glory.
3. Like Moses, God had bestowed his mighty power upon Jesus in order for Jesus to show the greatness of God to his followers.
4. Jesus is the Savior, through God. Believe in God and you will be saved.
5. The church looks at the Bible as a GUIDE and not as "the law of the land". This is a church that would rather go "the path less traveled" when it comes to the Bible. That might look at historical facts of Jesus including his Jewish background.
6. A church that does not push Christianity on non-believers.

What churches are at least similar to this?
Are there any sites that help one discuss their beliefs?

---

Background:

Since leaving the United Methodist Church in 2003, I've had a long spiritual journey. This journey has provided me with insight into God, Science, History, and Jesus. However, with my "new" insight, I don't know where to turn. I want to be more than spiritual. I want to find more people who believe along the lines that I believe, and most of all I want to belong (to a church).

In a nutshell, I believe that Jesus was merely a Rabbi (a teacher of God) who believed in the Jewish teachings in a different way to that of most Jews. His stories and teachings are very important and show us (especially non-Jews) how to believe in God. However, I believe that throughout the nearly 2000 years of Christian history, many people have "blurred"  the truth of the Bible by politics and other ways. My wife is Jewish and I have gone to many services, which has actually served to confirm my belief in Jesus.

Comment: Islam, maybe? :-)

Answer (score 3):

They may not be exact fits to your criteria, but the most likely options for you to investigate further would be possibly [Unitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism) (emphasis on inclusion regardless of specific beliefs) and perhaps more likely, [Quakerism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quakers) (inclusive, but with emphasis on Christ as the light within).

Both would most likely be accomodating towards your beliefs (not necessarily emphasizing the main points you raise however) while seeking to intentionally build communities of spiritually(-and-community)-minded people.
From the [Unitarian Universalist Association website](http://www.uua.org/):

> **Are My Beliefs Welcome?**
>
> In Unitarian Universalism, you can bring your whole self: your full identity, your questioning mind, your expansive heart.
>
> We are creating a force more powerful than one person or one religion. By welcoming people who identify with Atheism and Agnosticism, Buddhism, Christianity, Humanism, Judaism, Earth-Centered Traditions, Hinduism, Islam, and more, we are embodying a vision “beyond belief:” a vision of peace, love, and understanding.
>
> We are building an action-oriented community, bridging races, religions, and creeds with a shared desire to make faith, religion, and spirituality verbs.

[Here is a link](http://www.quaker.org/friends.html) to a brief introduction to the Quakers - also known as the Religious Society of Friends - which ticks at least some of your boxes:

> **The Place of the Bible**
>
> Friends hold that the words of the Bible should not be taken as the final revelation of God. The Books had been written by men who were acting under the power of the Holy Spirit and it was necessary to read the words in the power of the same spirit and to listen to what the Spirit then spoke in your heart. The words were active agents in the sense that, when read in the Spirit at the appropriate time, they would spring to life for the reader and take the reader forward on his or her spiritual journey.
>
> **The Light Within**
>
> George Fox [*the founder of Quakerism*] preached the Good News that we were all children of God and that, as children of God, we had inherited powers from God. Each of us was given a measure of this power or light and in accordance with how we used it, so more would be given to us. Jesus had possessed this power or light, without measure so that he became the Light and the Light within is Jesus Christ.

Comment: Note that the OP specifies some beliefs which may be considered too exclusive by some Unitarians or Quakers.

Comment: @curiousdannii While the OP has listed various doctrines, I don't believe he has over-emphasized the exclusive nature of them, if anything the opposite is actually implied (by 6. and some of the background). It's an interesting dilemma for groups that pride themselves on their inclusivity - how much 'exclusivity' in terms of the doctrines of attendees can they actually tolerate. I suspect that may vary substantially from congregation to congregation and would only be determinable by attendance.

Comment: @ bruised reed  Ive been to a Unitarian Church latley with friends. I didn't like it, it was to spiritual and not religious. It was like they were "beating around the bush" when it came to talking about Jesus. Yes the church might work, but I could see my self getting frustrated. Main reason the Unitarian Church doesn't directly discuss the wants I want out of a Church above. I'll go again, but I can tell it won't work out. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @BenjaminJones, Old Unitarianism, like in the 1700s and 1800s fits your description much better.  But the problem is, the views you outlined have no staying power.  They don't transmit to the next generation well.  And the end result is the group turns into "kumbaya everyone's ok you're ok I'm ok, there is no truth, all religions are equal" poppycock.

Comment: If only I had time machine.

Comment: @BenjaminJones Well, you could just try the Quakers instead.